# How to remove songs from vocals using audacity

Tags: audacity

If you search the web, you'll find a lot answers with this subject:

" How to Remove Vocals from Songs Using Audacity "

But i want to remove songs from the audio

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean, from a recording of a song, remove the instrumental accompaniment, leaving only the vocals?  "Remove songs from vocals" sounds surrealist.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I frequently call "the holy grail of the misinformed".

It cannot be done.

You cannot unbake a cake.

Give up now.

BTW, it usually doesn't work the other way round either. Flipping the phase of one side of the stereo pair will remove everything that is panned dead-centre; ie vocals, kick & snare, bass... yet not anything which isn't, like the vocal reverb.
End result is a) mono & b) sounds like $*****